# keeping a batch program running within set times

Tags: windows

I'm looking to ftp files (get and put) between two windows pcs. I have written the batch script to automatically do the ftp. But presently one needs to keep running it to do the puts and gets. Is there a way that I can get it to remain running between two set times (say 9am and 1pm) doing its gets and puts), then sleep/rest for a certain interval (say 5mins) then get and put all over again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Task Scheduler to keep running your batch file at designated times or at set intervals.